# NAV2 - compute_path_to_pose timeout

Tags: ros2, nav2

Timed out while waiting for action server to acknowledge goal request for compute_path_to_pose, while running nav2_bringup navigation_launch.py.

I'm using this script on RPi4, so I don't have many resources and it may happen that some process won't execute on time. Is there any way to extend the running time of compute_path_to_pose?

Comment: You can increase your code's timeout?

Comment: Can you clarify if the timeout issue you're facing happens when trying to connect to the action server, or does it occur during the movement execution phase?